# Reader = comm.ExecuteReader Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a code that checks whether my query generates rows with the use of `Reader.HasRows` Property. But I am stuck with this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

The Visual Studio Debugger says that the error comes from this statement:

> `Reader = comm.ExecuteReader`

This is the code:

```
    Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString

    MyConn.Open()
    Dim checkQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM ParentandGuardian WHERE First_Name = @FirstName AND Middle_Name = @MiddleName AND Last_Name = @LastName"
    Dim comm As New OleDbCommand(checkQuery, MyConn)

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", txtMiddleName)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName)

    Reader = comm.ExecuteReader

    If (Reader.HasRows) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Match Found")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("There are no matches found")
    End If
    MyConn.Close()

    Me.Close()
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You should investigate the `Errors` property of the exception.  It is a collection of `OleDbError` objects and hopefully it will contain something that can provide more specific information.  Whenever an exception is thrown, you should ALWAYS look at ALL the information provided by that exception.

Comment: are txtFirstName, txtMiddleName and txtLastName TextBox controls? If so you would need to use .Text property to get the values for each parameter.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Silly of me to left out .Text property. It works now @jmcilhinney - I'll keep your advice in mind.

Comment: @KarenPayne thank you for pointing out the problem.